# CSV file column minimum python

Tags: python, csv, math

```
Name  Gender Physics Maths
 A             45     55
 X             22     64
```

I have a csv file like the above. I want to find things like min, max etc based on subject
I have figured out the list in the form [[A , 45 , 55],[X , 22, 64]]

How do I separate the individual columns either from this list or from the whole csv file

I want to do this without csv module or pandas

```
for line in filename:
    line2 = line.strip()
    line2 = line2.split(',')
    line_min = min(float(i) for i in line2)
    minimum_marks.append(line_min)
    #minimum_marks.append(minimum_grades)

    print(minimum_marks)
```

I am getting an error

```
line_min = min(float(i) for i in line2)
```

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'C'

Comment: Can you not just iterate over the list of lists?

Comment: Easiest way (as you already have the data) might be list comprehension, see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: when I used maps it returned with some hexadecimal

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> line_min = min(float(i) for i in line2)
> ```
>
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'C'

`line2` is a list that looks something like this:

```
['Name', '88', '90']
```

Note that the first element is a name and can't be converted into an integer, so to fix your code use:

```
 line_min = min(float(i) for i in line2[1:])
```

To remove the first item of the list